# How to remove the subviews from a X number of buttons

Tags: iphone, view, for-loop, subview

I've got a view. Within there is a view. Within this view I placed a variable amount of buttons. Each buttons has some images (UIImageViews as subviews). I'd like to loop through a X amount of buttons and check if the button has more than 6 subviews. Afterwords I'd like to delete some subviews.

I succeeded implementing this for one button only but like to have it for a X amount of buttons. (let's say 56)

Here's a code snippit:

```
if([button.subviews count] >= 6){
        for ( int i = 1; i < 4; i++ ){
           [[button.subviews objectAtIndex:i] removeFromSuperview]; 
        }
```

I'm thinking I'm searching for a function like:

```
for(UIView *subview in [drawView subviews]){
   if([subview is kindOfClass:[UIButton class]]){
      //deleting subviews of the buttons here
   }
}
```

---

EDIT

Fixed it by using:

```
for(UIView *subview in [drawView subviews]){
   if([subview is kindOfClass:[UIButton class]]){
      if([subview.subviews count] =>6){
         for(int i = 1; i <4; i++){
            [[subview.subviews objectAtIndex:i] removeFromSuperview];
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Think of using a tab bar controller to call the same event on as many tabs as you want !

Comment: I'm more thinking of looping through all the buttons by putting an counting int (within a for statement) calling each button. like for(int = 0; i <57; i++) if([button+i.subviews count]>=6) etc. any clues?

Comment: I would say use the tag attribute for the buttons ! instead of keeping 57 buttons names use tags to call them.